# Twilio authorisation and calls

Tags: ios, twilio

I'm developing iOS application using Twilio SDK / Twilio Client. I issued the problem getting such error when trying to register or update capability token

```
2018-05-14 01:47:09.081975+0300 app-ios[9239:1187468] PJSIP(2):    pjsua_acc.c  ...SIP registration failed, status=408 (Request Timeout)
2018-05-14 01:47:09.083088+0300 app-ios[9239:1187284] Did stop listening for connections due to error Generic Error
```

Moreover when I trying to call another user I get such strange errors

```
OUTCOMING call started
2018-05-14 01:50:04.770308+0300 app-ios[9239:1188745] PJSIP(1):  pjsua_media.c !..Unable to resolve transport bind address: gethostbyname() has returned error (PJ_ERESOLVE) [status=70018]
2018-05-14 01:50:04.770354+0300 app-ios[9239:1188745] PJSIP(1):  pjsua_media.c  ..Unable to create RTP/RTCP socket: gethostbyname() has returned error (PJ_ERESOLVE) [status=70018]
2018-05-14 01:50:04.770375+0300 app-ios[9239:1188745] PJSIP(1):  pjsua_media.c  ..Error creating media transport: gethostbyname() has returned error (PJ_ERESOLVE)
2018-05-14 01:50:04.770394+0300 app-ios[9239:1188745] PJSIP(1):   pjsua_call.c  .Error initializing media channel: gethostbyname() has returned error (PJ_ERESOLVE) [status=70018]
interruptCall
2018-05-14 01:50:31.465743+0300 app-ios[9239:1187468] PJSIP(2):    pjsua_acc.c  ...SIP registration failed, status=408 (Request Timeout)
2018-05-14 01:50:31.466269+0300 app-ios[9239:1187284] Did stop listening for connections due to error Generic Error
2018-05-14 01:51:09.154605+0300 app-ios[9239:1187468] PJSIP(1): tlsc0x12681602  TLS connect() error: Operation timed out [code=120060]
```

I use all the examples found on github (PhoneKit, Official Quickstart) but no luck with communicating to someone not via device, not via simulator.
Delegates are set, plist settings are filled.
Backend should be working good, because similar Twilio Client - backed Android application works fine.

How can I fix it? Seems like this handy library doesn't want work with me :(

Comment: It looks like the SIP library that the Twilio Voice SDK is using is struggling to get an external connection. You're getting 408 responses, which says "Request Timeout". Are you able to make other network requests from your application?

Comment: @philnash Sure, there are some other API I call and successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I understood the root of the problem.

This [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1938/_index.html) tells us that legacy VoIP architecture is barely (in compatibility mode) supports in iOS 10, but I use Twilio Client with iOS 11 devices, which requires modern PushKit for VoIP support. Perhaps I could use iOS 10 SDK for building application that can work on iOS 11 devices, but don't think it makes much sense, because one become unable to upload app to AppStore.

Hope this information helps somebody, it's better to use PushKit-ready Twilio Voice.